# how to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 on the second disk while the second disk already has windows installed on it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

My device has 2 harddisks (ssd + windows and hdd) on the hdd I want to install ubuntu, I already tried to install it from usb (set it up with rufus, parameters: partition scheme - MBR, target system - BIOS or UEFI, file system - FAT32(default)) but at the end of the installation came the error "unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda/" as I understand ubuntu installed because the second attempt, the partition I allocated was already taken by ubbtu. I checked the properties of the disc I want to install the system on and there was an MBR, I don't really understand what it is, but somehow that's why I can't install the GRUB cobbler. I am new to installing systems and please help anyone who can.

Comment: You've not mention what Ubuntu product or release you're asking about. Ubuntu has a number of products which have their own releases, and not all use the same installers (*with a total of 5 installers available selected by ISO*). Are we to guess which you're asking about? as there are *slight* differences between them.  I'm also not sure what you mean by MBR; normally it's *master boot record* which relates to booting (cf. uEFI) but you maybe referring to *partition table* - but we don't know which installer you attempted to use.

Comment: Please be clear & full with details; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server (uses the `subiquity` installer), Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (using the `ubiquity` installer), or *flavors* (which can use `ubiquity` or `calamares`)..   You've added the release (20.04) but still haven't indicated if Server, Desktop (or less likely, but *flavor* too).   (20.04.6 is the *latest* ISO/release of 20.04 instead of the older one you mention which is short of many fixes that exist on the later ISOs)

Comment: You may want to edit the title of the question. It does not match what you are asking.